# How do I construct a matrix of vertices from 2 vectors?

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, vulkan

I'm writing a game engine in C++ that interacts with Vulkan. In order for me to be able to draw anything on the screen, I need to write vertices.

The game engine offers a slightly higher level interface to Vulkan, and it needs to be able to construct the vertices from a position Vector3 and a size Vector3.

I'm clueless on how to tackle this problem efficiently, anyone that may point me in the right direction? Thanks!!

```
class SquareMatrix {
public:
  Vector3 s1v1, s1v2, s1v3, s1v4, // Top
          s2v1, s2v2, s2v3, s2v4, // Bottom
          s3v1, s3v2, s3v3, s3v4, // Left
          s4v1, s4v2, s4v3, s4v4, // Right
          s5v1, s5v2, s5v3, s5v4, // Front
          s6v1, s6v2, s6v3, s6v4; // Back
  SquareMatrix(Vector3& v1, Vector3& v2) {
    std::array<std::array<Vector3, 4>, 6> Square;
    for(int a=0; a<=6; a++) {
      for(int b = 0; b <= 4; b++) {
        // Stumped!
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: It's really unclear as to exactly what you're trying to do here. You want to "write vertices", but to *what*? What do those vertices mean? How will you use them? Where do you want to write them to, and what will you do with them after writing them?

Comment: `s1v1` through `s6v4` looks a lot like you want a 2D array. Might make what you're stuck on a little easier.

Comment: These vertices will be used to draw 6 faces (which in total make a rectangle/square. These vertices will be used in Vulkan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two vectors are probably representing an "Axis Aligned Bounding Box" (AABB): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume

An AABB is a ractangular cuboid (i.e., 3D version of a rectangle) with the particularity that its edges are aligned wiyh the cartesian axis. That means that we can define any AABB using either a center point and the half-extents (size) of the box in the three orthogonal directions or two vertices which correspond to the min and max corners of the box.

So, in code you better define an struct AABB that contains two vertices with names such as minPoint and maxPoint.

Other thing is that you don't need to define 24 vertices. You only need 8 vertices. Then you need to define 6 faces, with each face containing 3 integers for triangles or 4 integers for quads, the integers are the indices of vertices. Vulkan should provide a render function with two parameters: list of vertices (probably an array of floats) and list of faces (probably an array of ints).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, the first thing you should do is use an array instead of a ton of fields in order to store vertices.

I assume that by writing the vertices you are writing it between calls to `vkMapMemory` and `vkUnmapMemory` (I am not a Vulkan expert lol). In this case, the most efficient way I can think of doing it would be to use an array of floats rather than an array of `Vertex3`s (otherwise you either have to copy one by one, or you have to find your way through standard layout, alignment requirements, and other stuff that is much more complicated than a simple array of floats), and write it using that. As for editing the float array, that is fairly straightforward. The other virtually equivalent option is a multidimensional array of floats, and in the case that the number of vertices is never going to change (is known at compile time), this also works (in any case, a simple array simply emulates a multidimensional array anyway).